# Classic ASP Image (PNG) Manipulation

Tags: image-processing, asp-classic

I am writing a little application in classic asp (don't judge me, I don't have a choice) where I need to offer users a choice of PNG and a choice of colors, then I need to display the image among other html elements.  The color will essentially come from a color selector, so there will be endless choices and I don't really have the option of making every PNG in every possible color.  Does anybody know of a script I could use for this, or should I just take a crack at making one from scratch?

Comment: Does the PNG need to change color, or the background? PNGs have transparency, so maybe you can put it in a DIV with a background color and keep the PNG the same. I have done something similar with buttons that had a gradient and different colors. The PNG was just a gradient.

Comment: No, the shape itself needs to change color.  This is how I started doing it, but I need to be able to use a background image and a variable color PNG.

Comment: If you can have .NET application sitting on the same server (not instead, in addition to the classic ASP application) it's possible to "consume" .NET page that generates such PNG from the clasic ASP code. Otherwise, your only option is using third party components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/ImageMagickObject.html).
They both have a COM component you can install and use from ASP. They allow image manipulation from code.

Using .NET like suggested above will do the same thing, but it's equally possible in classic ASP (or other languages like perl or Python) using one of these two components.
Mind you: It will not be a simple thing to do, but essentially what you want is to manipulate images with code, and more specifically change one color, which is tricky in most programming languages.

Here are a few links to get you started:

[Using ImageMagick from classic ASP](http://joeraff.org/20120124/manipulating-images-using-classic-asp/)

[Replacing a color with ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18196)

Answer (score 0):

Even we can take color code from color picker and assign it as the background color something like this

```
 color = "#3B0B0B"
```